# Android Activity which overridden functions must call super.*

Tags: java, android, android-activity, overriding

When creating own Activity subclass, we are overriding some of the basic Activity lifecycle functions.

In which of these we **must** call super implementation, where we **should** and where is it **only good manner** ?

```
// base lifecycle
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
onStart();
onRestart();
onResume();
onPause();
onStop();
onDestroy();
finalize();
onUserLeaveHint();
// instance state
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState);
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
// others
onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo);
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu);
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item);
onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item);
onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item);
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
onBackPressed();
```

*List of methods is not final, feel free to add more functions, where we should know, what to do.*

---

For those who are interested in, where should be `super.methodName` placed
[Locations of super() calls in Android Eclipse Plugin generated code reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994959/locations-of-super-calls-in-android-eclipse-plugin-generated-code-reliable)

Comment: Android will throw a RuntimeException if you forget to call the super method although it would be necessary.

Comment: Superclass at FIRST: `onRestoreInstanceState، onStop, onRestart, onStart`. Superclass at LAST: `onDestroy, onPause, onSaveInstanceState, onResume`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**must:**

- `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);`
- `onStart();`
- `onRestart();`
- `onResume();`
- `onPause();`
- `onStop();`
- `onDestroy();`
- `onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);`
- `onPostResume();`

**should / shouldn't:**
(may be helpful to call superclass method, unless you manage activity's state or deliberately alter activity's behavior yourself - in such case it may be harmful)

- `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState);`
- `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState);`
- `onBackPressed();`
- `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo);`
- `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu);`
- `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item);`
- `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item);`
- `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item);`

Actually, when overriding any method, it's a good practice to look at the source code of the overridden class and see what exactly this method does.

Comment: great, at least you, answered my question :) Thanks

Comment: would you please explain how you categorized these methods into "must" and "should"? I am a beginner and I am trying to understand how to figure out which methods should have a call to super(). I don't want to just remember and recall when needed... I want to understand how to figure it out

Comment: I've slightly updated the answer. Basically, there are methods you must call (you'll know it from the methods' description, from Lint hints or from exceptions you'll get) and methods that affect the behavior of the Activity/Fragment in a certain way.

Comment: Superclass at FIRST: `onRestoreInstanceState، onStop, onRestart, onStart`. Superclass at LAST: `onDestroy, onPause, onSaveInstanceState, onResume`.

Answer (score 4):

Its just a good practice to call the super implementation.
BUT some times its mandatory, like in "onCreate()", else there will be an "ActivityInstantiateingexcepetion"in this case.
Also, some times you want to override the super implementation in some cases, like 
 `onBackPressed(){

if(myFlag){
// do my stuff 
}
 else { 
 // Do usual stuff on Back pressed 
super.onBackPressed (); 
}`

So this way if your "myFlag" will be true, your stuff will be done else normal onBackpressed will be executed.

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad: thanks, why dont you vote up my answer in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

Its all `Activity` class method.In Java and Android if you call `superclass` method ,You must write `super.methodName`

Answer (score 0):

all these methods should call super.method() I think