# Which overridden methods should have a call to super and where?

Tags: java, android

I am referring the big nerd ranch android book for learning android.

When overriding `Activity` or `Fragment` methods, I have come across places where the call to `super()` is removed, and some places where it is kept as a part of the overriding method.

How can I understand that which methods need the `super()` and which don't?

And if the `super()` is to be kept... is it always on the first line? I ask this because while searching for an answer, I came across this

```
public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

On a humble note: I have seen the posts

[Android Activity which overridden functions must call super.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892383/android-activity-which-overridden-functions-must-call-super/8892645#comment56264563_8892645)

and

[Locations of super() calls in Android Eclipse Plugin generated code reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994959/locations-of-super-calls-in-android-eclipse-plugin-generated-code-reliable)

but it didn't clear my doubts. So I hope I am not breaking any rules by posting this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843452

Comment: you should spend sometime on override method on Java first, for more understanding about how/when/where/why super() method works

Comment: @LinhNguyen I have worked with java for 2 years, I am well aware how `super()` works. But in Android, sometimes `super()` is used and sometimes it isn't... and that's what the question is about

Comment: you will come to the answer if you get the difference between call the super() method at the first line and the last