# Which Android Fragment lifecycle methods require super

Tags: android, overriding, super

Currently (Android API 17), the only mention of `super` in the Android [Reference on Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) is casually via some code examples (unlike the Android [Reference on Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), which carefully notes where `super` is required).

SO suggests [searching the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843383/why-do-we-have-to-call-super-in-android-sometimes) as needed, or waiting for a crash, to identify where a call to `super` is required.  I'm asking SO users to share their knowledge on which of the Fragment lifecycle methods require a call to `super`.

### Fragment lifecycle methods - require call to `super`

- `onAttach()`
- `onCreate()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it
- `onCreateView()` - seems ok with or without
- `onActivityCreated()`
- `onViewStateRestored()`
- `onStart()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it
- `onResume()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it
- `onPause()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it
- `onStop()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it
- `onDestroyView()`
- `onDestroy()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it
- `onDetach()`
- `onSaveInstanceState()` - presumably yes, as `Activity` version requires it

Comment: i know this does not answer your question, but it won't hurt to call super always.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman  That's a dangerous statement.  I can think of several class methods where calling super or not changes the semantics.  onDraw() for example.  I don't know the answer to the OP but it's a valid, and important question.

Comment: I am with @Jeffrey Blattman, and would go with the assumption that calling `super` is always required, except in specific cases. Thus, i would flip the question and phrase it as `"For which methods calling super can have side effects and should not be done"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the corresponding Activity lifecycle methods except `onSaveInstanceState` require calls to super. In addition:

- `onAttach()` - yes
- `onActivityCreated()` - yes
- `onViewStateRestored()` - is not a Fragment method
- `onDestroyView()` - yes
- `onDetach()` - yes
- `onSaveInstanceState()` - from [Fragment#onSaveInstanceState](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/Fragment.java#Fragment.onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) it
  looks like a no

All of the methods that require calls to super share the first line of their method in android.app.Fragment: 
`mCalled = true;`

That way the FragmentManager can check if mCalled is true and throw a SuperNotCalledException when it is not called. See [FragmentManager#moveToState](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState%28android.app.Fragment,int,int,int,boolean%29) to see this implementation.

Comment: many thx; got the android source from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest , and can now see the corresponding fragment code and `mCalled` statements.  SO Q with some additional info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843383/why-do-we-have-to-call-super-in-android-sometimes#comment14121604_10843452

Answer (score 0):

When generating a fragment with Eclipse, the onCreateView method template code does not have a call to super.onCreateView. Also, the generally quite good book published by WROX: Android 4 Application Development misses it out in its sample lifetime code (it does not miss out any other calls to super).

Of course both these two sources could be incorrect, but using the Eclipse template and not adding super.onCreateView has not caused me an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am typing with capital letter 'O' instead of small letter 'o'

means : OnCreate instead of onCreate methods.

Its a silly mistake but need to remember :)

Thanks