# The definitive list of Android lifecycle calls requiring super.method()

Tags: java, android, overriding

I'm trying to get a list of all Android lifecycle methods that require calling the superclass method.  There was a good list started in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532182/which-android-fragment-lifecycle-methods-require-super).  I'm not asking because of an error in my code, but because I want a tool to detect this specific problem.

To find the list, I searched the API 18 docs for the following strings:

- Derived classes must call through to the super class's
- if you override this method
- superclass
- SuperNotCalledException from platform sources

I ended up with the following list. I removed derived classes that have the same message as the parent.

- Application (MockApplicaition)

  - onCreate()
- Activity/ActivityGroup (Fragment/DialogFragment, ListActivity, TabActivity, LauncherActivity, NativeActivity, et. al)

  - onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
  - onDestroy()
  - onPause()
  - onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
  - onPostResume()
  - onRestart()
  - onResume()
  - onStart()
  - onStop()
  - onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
  - onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) - Depends
  - onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) - Depends
  - onActionModeStarted(android.view.ActionMode) - Recommended
  - onActionModeFinished(android.view.ActionMode) - Recommended
  - onPrepareDialog(int, android.app.Dialog, android.os.Bundle) - Recommended
- Fragment

  - onAttach(FragmentActivity)
  - onDetach()
  - onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)
  - onActivityCreated(Bundle)
  - onDestroyView()
- Dialog (AlertDialog, DatePickerDialog, ProgressDialog, Presentation, et. al)

  - onActionModeStarted(android.view.ActionMode) - Recommended
  - onActionModeFinished(android.view.ActionMode) - Recommended
- ViewPager

  - onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
  - drawableStateChanged()
- View/ViewGroup (ListView, TextView, KeyboardView, et. al.)

  - onAnimationStart()
  - onAnimationEnd()
  - onMeasure(int, int) - Required to call setMeasuredDimension(int, int)
  - draw(android.graphics.Canvas)
- Preference/PreferenceGroup (CheckBoxPreference, et. al.)

  - onBindView(android.view.View)
  - onCreateView(android.view.ViewGroup)
  - onPrepareForRemoval()
  - <strike>onCommonsWare()</strike>

Is this the definitive list?

**EDIT** Based on feedback from @CommonsWare, added methods that trigger SuperNotCalledException

Comment: I would instead search for occurrences of `SuperNotCalledException` in the source -- if that's not thrown, you should be able to avoid the `super` call. Also note that `onCommonsWare()` is deprecated prior to API Level 42.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Good point. As soon as my build box stops emitting smoke from building a certain OEM Android distro, I'll grep.  Then I'll update this list.

Comment: Updated list using SuperNotCalledException.  Thanks @commonsware!

Comment: Can anyone weigh in on why this seems to be so poorly documented?  Pretty sure I remember reading something about OOP and hiding implementation details, so I don't think that reading the class source and seeing if it might break for unknown reasons if `super` isn't called is a sound programming technique.  And what about methods like `Fragment#onCreateView` where it can go either way?  Bizzare.