# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity which has 2 buttons. The fragment in my activity would change on button click. But I am facing issue as -- `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment` .
Below is my code-

### `activity_main.xml`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="selectFrag"
        android:text="Select Fragment 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="selectFrag"
        android:text="Select Fragment 2" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:name="com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo.FragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
        Fragment fr = null;

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
            fr = new FragmentTwo();

        } else {
            fr = new FragmentOne();
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

### `FragmentOne.java`

```
package com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Fragment Demo", "Fragment_One onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

### `fragment_one.xml`

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo.FragmentOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFragment_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This is Fragment 1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

similar to `FragmentOne.java` and `fragment_two.xml`, my code has `FragmentTwo.java` and `fragment_two.xml` respectively.

I get exception as--

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo/com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
        at com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment FragmentOne{3fdec5ae #0 id=0x7f0c0051} did not call through to super.onCreate()
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1768)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.example.rahul.fragmentdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

-- where `MainActivity.java:18` refers to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error log says, there is missing `super.onCreate` in `FragmentOne.java`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("Fragment Demo", "Fragment_One onCreate()");
}
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks :) can you please tell me why do we have to call super class method super.onCreate() ? And why not for other functions ?

Comment: @Ahuja I have not cared about that because I almost always use super call. This [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532182/which-android-fragment-lifecycle-methods-require-super) may help you.