# Should super() be called implicitly or explicitly?

Tags: java, constructor, super

I learned that when constructing an object, `super()` will be called, whether you write it in the constructor or not. But I noticed that in some code, the `super()` method is called explicitly. Should I be calling `super()` implicitly or explicitly in a constructor? What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we have to call super in Android sometimes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843383/why-do-we-have-to-call-super-in-android-sometimes)

Comment: Doesn't matter unless you plan on passing parameters to the super class's constructor. The compiler inserts it for you if you leave it out. If there's no default c'tor in the superclass then you _must_ call it explicitly with the appropriate arguments passed to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was reading the source code of Exception class,when I found the default constructor of Excetion has only a super() inside. And I'm confused.Now I got it.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I call the super() method implicitly or explicitly in a constructor? What's the difference?

There is no semantic difference between calling `super()` or not, and no performance difference either.

This is purely a cosmetic issue.  Make up your own mind ... or go with what (if anything) your project's adopted style guide says.

---

<sup>On the other hand, if the `super` you need to call has parameters, then it *does* matter that you call it explicitly.  And if the superclass doesn't have a no-args constructor, then you can't use `super()`, either explicitly or implicitly.</sup>

Comment: Now I know it much better

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference if the discussion is around **no-argument** `super()` constructor.

Java calls `super()` implicitly for all your base class constructors if not called explicitly. Remember Java only calls super class no-argument constructor always.

In some cases, as a developer you may want to call **argument-based** super constructor. In those cases, you have to **explicitly** call argument-based super constructor eg: `super(arg1, arg2, ...)`

IMO, avoid calling no-argument `super()` constructor since it neither have any impact on logic nor improves readability.