# Unimplemented OnCreate() method does not give an error

Tags: android, android-activity

```
package com.example.mytests;

import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {}
```

For the code above, even though I do not implement `OnCreate()` method I get no errors and program works. Should't I get an error that I should override it?

Comment: `onCreate(Bundle)` is not abstract so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You will get error if you override `onCreate` and forget to call `super.onCreate` first thing.

In your case just `Activity.onCreate()` gets called. It can't really give an error, unless they in Google break something severily which they do not. If it gave Android wouldn't work because the same error would come from `super.onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to override it. But if you DO override it, you MUST call `super.onCreate()`.

The idea is that no matter what, the default implementation of onCreate() must be called, which is also the case if you do not override it at all.

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate` is one of the Life Cycle methods of the `Activity`

Reason we implement the `onCreate` because some where we need to set the content view to the activity. For that reason we choose `onCreate` for `setContentView()` and it is the first life cycle method to be called. and if you override the `onCreate` dont forgot to call the  `super.onCreate()`

[why super.onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843383/why-do-we-have-to-call-super-in-android-sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

You are extending class which has already defined onCreate method so overriding indicates to use your behavior.otherwise super class behavior will b used.this is same as extend thread class and not override run method.here do nothing run method will b invoked when u call start method on thread . You might be confused in implementing and extending interface or class.