# Mandatory calling superclass methods of an Android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, superclass

In the life cycle of an activity, is needed to call to methods of parent class always? .What I mean is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

 }



protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


}



protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

}


public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}


 public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
```

And do I always have to call the super class method first? For example:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    .....my code.......
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}


 public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     .......my code...... 

}
```

On onSaveInstanceState method it has more sense to write my code first and after to the superclasss method and on onRestoreInstanceState method the opossite?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we have to call super in Android sometimes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843383/why-do-we-have-to-call-super-in-android-sometimes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the lifecycle methods indicate if calling `super.onXXX()` is required or not. For some methods this is required, for some it is not.

For the lifecycle methods which require calling through to `super.onXXX()`, you can call that method at any time. It can be before or after your code.

For `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, it should also make no difference whether you call `super.onXXX()` before or after your code. Hopefully, the stuff that you put in the saved instance `Bundle` does not conflict with the stuff that the Android framework is putting in the `Bundle`. If it conflicts, you'll have a problem no matter whether you call the `super` method before or after your code.

NOTE: The Android framework uses the following keys when putting View and Dialog information in the saved instance `Bundle`:

```
 static final String FRAGMENTS_TAG = "android:fragments";
 private static final String WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG = "android:viewHierarchyState";
 private static final String SAVED_DIALOG_IDS_KEY = "android:savedDialogIds";
 private static final String SAVED_DIALOGS_TAG = "android:savedDialogs";
 private static final String SAVED_DIALOG_KEY_PREFIX = "android:dialog_";
 private static final String SAVED_DIALOG_ARGS_KEY_PREFIX = "android:dialog_args_";
```

so as long as you don't use keys with the same names, you should be good.