# Image taken from gallery doesn't appear

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I use Picasso to get an image from the gallery and set it to an ImageView, but it does not do it. Couldn't find a problem. What is the reason? And the interesting thing is that there was no error. I tested the program through my own device.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String imageUri ;
    ImageView img ;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 9391;
    Button b ;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData().toString() ;
            loadImage() ;
        }
        else
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void loadImage() {
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri).fit().centerInside().into(img);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button) ; // it is button used to open //a gallery
    }

    //thins function called when button pressed
    public void openGallery(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_PICK,EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) ;

        startActivityForResult(i,GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Picasso.Listener` [to see if there was an error in Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628461/115145).

Comment: I've noticed that onImageLoadFailed method called. But couldn't understand why?

Comment: If you used the code from the answer that I linked to, there will be a Java stack trace in LogCat that explains what went wrong.

Comment: which version of android you are using?

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary Latest version 2.2.3

Comment: I am not asking for Android Studio version ,asking Android version(Naugat,Marshmello)??

Comment: Lollipop. Problem already solved. I forgot to add permission (

Answer (score 0):

You called `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` which is wrong .

Do this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();                 

 Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImageURI).fit().centerInside().into(img);
    }
    else
    {
        // handle this case
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how this would affect Picasso's ability to load the image.

Comment: you try it and do let me know please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843383/why-do-we-have-to-call-super-in-android-sometimes

Comment: @quicklearner Anyways,it didn't work for me. I've noticed that program's if statement had worked. It means image had to be set. But why it does not work?

Comment: yeah now you have to she image,when you get the data in onactivity result

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

I forgot to add permission used to read external storage.