# Calling super at end

Tags: java, android, overriding

i am really confused by the way people use super in overridden methods .
Like what is the different between

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    // some logic here 
    super.onResume();
  }
```

and

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // some logic here 
  }
```

Does it perform any pre-processing when we call super() at the end , because generally we call super to initialize parent constructor.

Any difference in performance with both kinds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994959/locations-of-super-calls-in-android-eclipse-plugin-generated-code-reliable

Comment: You are confusing constructor calls with method calls (`super.method()`. Also your code does not compile.

Comment: Superclass at FIRST: `onRestoreInstanceState، onStop, onRestart, onStart`. Your codes at FIRST: `onDestroy, onPause, onSaveInstanceState, onResume`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly, plain `super()` isn't allowed in *methods* at all - only in constructors. I assume you actually meant `super.someMethod()` for an appropriate method.

> Does it perform any pre-processing when we call super() at the end , because generally we call super to initialize parent constructor .

Using `super` in a method is somewhat different to using it in a constructor.

In a constructor, `super` (or `this`) is *required* to be the very first statement (if present, with an implicit `super()` otherwise) and it can *only* call a constructor.

In a method, using `super.someMethod()` simply calls the superclass implementation of `someMethod`. You can call it from *any* method (you don't have to be overriding `someMethod` at the time) and you can call it at any point in the method. It's invoked at the point you call it, it just avoids the polymorphic call to an overriding implementation.

So basically where - and whether - you call it depends on what you want the effect to be. In some cases you *may* want to call the superclass implementation of the same method before your own custom behavior, and in some cases you *may* want to call it after your own custom behaviour.

Comment: In Google examples, Superclass called at FIRST in `onRestoreInstanceState، onStop, onRestart, onStart`.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub: That may happen to be the case for those methods, but there's no language rule about it, and in some cases you may want to do that *last*.

Comment: No, that's what Prof "Andrew T. Campbell" said, same as Google: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture05/lecture05.html

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub: Again, you're talking about *a specific method implementation* (or recommended overrides for a specific method). I'm talking about the general rules of the language - it's entirely possible for a method to override another, do other work and then call `super.foo()`. If you don't believe me, try it.

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on the logic that the method implements. Sometimes it is called first, sometimes at the end, and sometimes never. For example, if some calculation from superclass method is really important, then it will be called first. Or if calculation is attempted in subclass method but without a good result (result is null) attempt is made on subclass method. There is really no good answer to this question except that it really depends.

---

Example 1:

A label provider that extrapolates time from the `Date` object and returns it to the UI for showing:

```
public class TimeLabelProvider {
    public String getText(Date element) {
        //extrapolate time from the element
        return time;
    }
}
```

A label provider that extrapolates both date and time from the `Date` object and returns it to the UI for showing:

```
public class DateTimeLabelProvider extends TimeLabelProvider {
    @Override 
    public String getText(Date element) {
         //extrapolate date from the element
         String date = ...

         //now get time string. We don't need to repeat logic, 
         //its already implemented in super method!
         String time = super.getText(element);
         return date + " " + time;
    }
}
```

Example 2:

If your project has a deep class hierarchy for UI elements, e.g.

```
DropDownField extends TextField extends Field extends AbstractField
```

Now, each of the classes added some UI elements to the field, for example, `DropDownField` added a menu and a little arrow to the right of the field, `TextField` added a validator, `AbstractTextField` added a white block to write text, etc... To dispose elements you would have to do multilevel disposal like this:

```
public class DropDownField extends TextField {

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        menu.dispose();
        arrow.dispose();
        //let text field dispose of its elements
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at okPressed() method for swt dialogs. Usually people override okPressed on a dialog to do some desired work. The super.okPressed() usually disposes the dialog doing nothing. So it is called in the end after all your work is done.

```
public void okPressed()
{
   ///Do your work
   super.okPressed()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as to whether to call back to the super method in the first line, or the last line of your method ... it depends on the semantic of the super method. in other words, there's no way to know other than looking at the documentation (or code) for the method. there may also be cases where you don't want to call through to the super method at all.

you seem to be asking about `onResume()`. while the docs don't say, the pattern i've always used is to call back to the super method in the first line. for `onPause()`, i call back in the last line. the idea is that the super methods wrap your custom pause / resume logic ...

```
super on resume
custom on resume
...
custom on pause
super on pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword super is a way to call a parent class behavior in a specialized class.

In a constructor, calling

```
super(args)
```

let you choose which constructor of the parent class should be used.

In a method, calling

```
super.parentMethod(args)
```

let you call the parent class behavior even if current class override parentMethod. Typically it would be used to add some logic before or after the parent class.

Calling

```
super();
```

in a method won't compile since you used the constructor super syntax in a method.